# How can I create <select> optgroups in html using data from mysql?

Tags: php, html, select, optgroup

SO I have about 60 fields of data queried from a database. They look like this in page source:

```
    <option>Genesis</option>
    <option>Exodus</option>
    <option>Leviticus</option>
```

For example I wanna have it so that 1-20 are a certain optgroup and then 20-60 is another. Could I do it using my format of options of would they have to be numbered like this:

```
<option value="1">Genesis</option>
<option value="2">Exodus</option>
<option value="3">Leviticus</option>
```

This is for my php class, but i dont think php is involved in making optgroups here, or is it? Thank you hope you understand my question. Hoping for help.

I pull the data from mysql using this :

```
//Query the database for the results we want
$query = $mysqli->query("select distinct bname as Name from kjv"); ?>
```

And then output it in the select dropdown box using this:

```
    <select>
    <?php while($option = $query->fetch_object()){ ?>
        <option><?php echo $option->Name; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Where you say "and then 2-60 is another" you mean "and then 20-60 is another", right? Do you want to create a new optgroup for each group of x options (where x is a number)?

Comment: Since `<optgroup>` is HTML, it should be generated by the PHP. What is your PHP code?

Comment: I meant 20-60 is another group sry

Comment: how do you store the values? are they in a php array? is the array associative?

Comment: I added the way I store values in the OP

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
<select>
    <?php 
    $i=1;
    while($option = $query->fetch_object()){ 
        if($i%10==1) echo "<optgroup label='Option Group'>";
        echo "<option value='$i'>".$option->Name."</option>";
            $i++;
        if($i%10==1) echo "</optgroup>";
    } 
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: About to try this. Ill let you know how it went

Comment: Some changes is made try now

Comment: Thank man it added optgroups to my output now I just need to put them in the right places and im done.

Comment: Another change is in answer and it is tested.

Comment: This one gives me an optgroup every 10 lines starting from line 1, the last one had the first optgroup at line 11, not 1.

Comment: However it gives the same optgroup every x number of lines. How would I go about actually making different ones?

Answer (score 0):

Using while loop :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM example"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

foreach ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

 echo "'<option value={$row['id']}>{$row['value']}</option>'";

}
```